# Prolog Insert list as element into another List

Tags: list, prolog

In my program my P = [0,1,2] I want to store it into another LIST, because P will keep changing in a loop so I want to store P into a LIST, so my LIST will be like below :

eg. 
LIST = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

create_list([],[]).
create_list(G, [H|G]).

This is what I did, create_list(P,LIST). I not sure how to do it as it keep return me no. But I am pretty sure I can get different P because I am able to print them out each time P changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a predicate that receives the item (list in this case) you want to append to another input list, and this would give you a new list with the which has all the items of your input list plus the new item.

So, it would be something like:

```
create_list(Item, List, [Item|List]).
```

Initially the input List would be an empty list ([]), so you might call it

```
create_list([0,1,2], [], List1),
create_list([3,4,5], List1, List2),
create_list([6,7,8], List2, List).
```

This will result in List instantiated with [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have a  find_P(A,B):-path(A, B, Path), create_list(Path,List,List), fail.  so my find_P will return me diff possible list and store in Path. then I call create_list(Path,List,List). so each time the Path will be added into the List. Does it correct?

Comment: No, that won't work because when you `fail` the output list will get unbounded again. You should use metapredicate findall in your scenario

Comment: You might want to change your sample code to something like: `find_P(A,B, List):- findall(Path, path(A,B,Path), List).`

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner of Prolog, so inside my find_P:- i call findall then call create_list?

Comment: I think you should use the predicate I wrote in my previous comment 'as is'. It will return in List the list of possible paths from A to B.

Comment: Thanks for your advised, I had updated my question with the code I trying to run. if I call find_P(1,4,List). it will return me no.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4197/discussion-between-gusbro-and-user236501)